# Range-based for loop and std::vector: are elements processed in order?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, stdvector

I am using a `std::vector` where the first element is somehow special, and need a *slightly* different handling than other elements.

I would like to use the C++11 range-based for loop for more readability, is the following code correct and good practice in this situation?

```
std::vector<T> v;

// [...] build v

bool isFirst = true;
for(auto element : v) 
{
    // [...] do lots of things common to all elements

    if(isFirst)
    {
        // [...] do something that only applies to the first element
    }

    // [...] do lots of things common to all elements

    isFirst = false;       
}
```

More technically, when using a range-based for loop with `std::vector`, are elements guaranteed to be processed in order, from `v.front()` to `v.back()`?

Comment: As a side note, storing if the element is "special" directly in `T` would really be over-engineering, as `T` is used in other places, this "specialness" is only relevant in this piece of code, and creating a new `struct Tbis { bool isSpecial; T t; }` makes the code really less readable inside the for loop.

Comment: You could just take it out of the vector, and or have it in two places rather than going to all this trouble, BTW even if you can get it to work where you check for being the first elem every time, that would just be a needless inefficiency

Comment: @aaronman No, I don't think I can, as written in the provided code, the special handling has to happen in the middle of a lot of other common operations, you can't just do it outside the for loop. And since this algorithm is rather subtle, bug prone, and subject to change (it's research), duplicating the "common part" of the loop is really not an option.

Comment: Then check out my answer which doesn't do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are elements guaranteed to be processed in order

Yes.

A range-based `for` of the form `for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement` will be evaluated equivalently to: [stmt.ranged]/1

```
{
    auto && __range = range-init;
    for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
               __end = end-expr;
               __begin != __end;
               ++__begin ) {
        for-range-declaration = *__begin;
        statement
    }
}
```

Where the *range-init* is `(expression)` (with the *expression* after the colon in the original range-based for statement), `begin-expr` essentially is `begin(__range)` and `end-expr` essentially is `end(__range)`.

---

> is the following code correct and good practice in this situation?

I'll provide an alternative rather than judging (-> [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)):

```
template<class It>
struct range
{
    It beg;
    It en;
    It begin() { return beg; }
    It end() { return en; }
};

template<class It>
range<It> make_range(It beg, It en) { return {beg, en}; }

std::vector<int> v;

if(v.size() > 0)
{
    auto r = make_range(begin(v)+1, end(v));
    for(auto const& e : r)
    {
        // do.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it more readable? I'm not sure. It depends on if you can factor out the things you do with all elements, so that you can treat the first element outside the loop without duplicating code.

Comment: Ok, thx a lot :) The question of readability is of course debatable, but at least it looks more readable to me right now, which is what's important since likely no one else will ever use this code.

Comment: The *guarantee* that the elements will be processed in order is only partly true. Some compilers (e.g. gcc) support loop parallelization - which works only if the iterations are independent. In this specific case, the 'isFirst' flag creates a dependence between iterations, which would prevent the first iteration from being executed in parallel with subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course they are processed in order otherwise they would have an extremely limited use. Here's another way you could do it.

```
std::vector<T> v;

// [...] build v

auto front = v.front();
/* do stuff to first */
for(auto iter = v.begin()+1; iter != v.end() ; ++iter) 
{
    //*iter is now the element incase you didn't know how iterators work
    // [...] do lots of things common to all elements
}
```

This avoids all the checking for being first element, and doesn't add much code

Comment: Yeah... good ol' iterators. But it suffers from the same problems as my solution: 1) you need to check `v.size() > 0` or `v.begin()+1` is UB. 2) Whether or not it's more readable depends on how easily you can factor out the code applied to all elements.

Comment: @DyP yeah I thought of that part, I know nothing about his data but I'll leave it to him to decide if it's even a possible situation that his data is of size 0, I figure if the first elem is so special there will prolly always be one

Comment: Thx too :) In my case the common stuff has also to be applied to the first guy, so using v.begin()+1 is not appropriate, but I can replace your loop by the whole loop (using range-based, possibly). But in my case, using this approach, I would need a loop before the special handling, and a loop after, which would work but looks rather weird (doing half the work to all elements, then the other half to all elements), and makes it less readable in my opinion (and I guess introduce some overhead, though should not be an issue here)

Comment: @Boris wait a sec, then why don't you just do the stuff to the first element and then use a normal range based for loop, the fact that you have such specific needs makes me think you may have somehow programmed yourself into a hole

Comment: I compute a graph based on intersections between hand drawn curves (nodes of the graph are intersections, edges are the (sub-)curves themselves), and I need to cluster different nodes together based on some tolerance, to account for drawing innacurracies and allow the user to draw star-like intersections. Clustering the nodes implies retargetting the drawn curves to ensure the geometry is consistent with the topology. How cluster are computed and curves retargetted is slightly different depending if a new node is created by self-intersections, or interestion with previously drawn curves.

Comment: (continuing) but for most of the algorithm, it doesn't really matter if the node is from a self-intersection or an intersection with a previously drawn curve.

Comment: @Boris sounds like a blast, not sure how that's responding to my comment, good luck

Comment: "you may have somehow programmed yourself into a hole": I was just claryfying my situation :-) "why don't you just do the stuff to the first element and then use a normal range based for loop": I just can't, the special handling appears at several parts **in the middle** of a common algorithm that apply to all elements, including this special one.

Comment: @Boris at least you gave an SSCCE instead of posting 3k lines of code, kudos for that. Just for the hell of it if you wanna make range based for loops a more useful feature, me and my friend wrote this [library](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools) check it out if you want